# Centering horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering

The title and navigation bar of my website have absolute positioning so they will stay put while the images scroll under.

http://www.mikegarten.com/

I am trying to center the whole site horizontally.

I tried with [this method](https://coderwall.com/p/quutdq) but was unsuccessful.

I have tried to put my images into a table then centering that in a `div`, but then the horizontal images have empty space above and below created by the grid from vertical photos in the same row.

Is it possible to “wrap” this site, or do I need to use another approach?

Comment: Just a recommendation. It's bad practice to make everything positioned absolutely.

Comment: ^ Agreed. Good practice is to nest any `absolute` items in a `relative` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the left css property to 50% then add a margin-left of half the width of the  element * -1, so to center your name element, set the left property to 50% and the margin-left to -132px;

```
#name {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -132px;
}

#navtext {
    position: fixed;
    top: 105px;
    background-color: none;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left: -500px;
}
```

For your 3 columns you will need to place them in a wrapper div and set the width on it to your desired width and the margin-left and margin-right to auto.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three non-deprecated ways to center something horizontally.

- [`margin: auto`](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center#block) ([explained at LearnLayout.com](http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html))
- [ugly hacking of `position`](https://coderwall.com/p/quutdq) with a wrapper element (the question links to that)
- even uglier hacking of `position`, this time setting `position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -<half the width of this box>`

I recommend using the first method. You have to make sure the element you want to center has `display: block`, `float: none` and `position` set to `normal` or `relative`. Also it has to have limited width (less than 100 % of its parent), which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There is `<center></center>` tags in html, however I think this is outdated. 
the other way is to center it using CSS giving it a width and margin:auto;

Comment: Just to confirm `center` tags are deprecated and shouldn't be used

Answer (score 0):

You have made all the grid elements you have on your site `position:absolute`. That's why it won't center, because you've told it to be in an exact position. Also, it would help if you wrapped your grids in a wrapper div so you can position them as a whole.

Use width and margins. You can then use padding to space out the rest of the grid elements.